# Android - adb shell input text

Tags: android

Android - I want to pass a large string using adb shell command. Is there a restriction on the length of the input string ?

$ adb shell input text

Comment: Try it... you won't be able to believe any of the lies they'll tell you here anyway ;-)

Comment: Try piping it in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278587/pipe-into-adb-shell.

Answer (score 0):

According to my search. Max length for `adb shell input text` is **1024 bytes**.
Here is the code of `adb_client.c` Android 4.4

```
if((len < 1) || (len > 1024)) {
   strcpy(__adb_error, "service name too long");
   return -1;
}
```

Reference: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-4.4_r1/adb/adb_client.c#184